# Java calendar.getTimeInMillis() returns extra zeros?

Tags: java, calendar

I am using a Java `Calendar` object to set a date and then get the time in milliseconds in order to determine chronology of two different epochs. Seemed to be a great plan until I went to double-check the returned value from `getTimeInMillis()`.
 **Fri Jul 17 00:00:00 CDT 2009** returns 1247806800**000** which doesn't seem to jive when I test the returned value with Perl which tells me this epoch should really be 1247806800 (short 3 zeros).

Where are these extra zeros coming from? The Java docs just say getTimeInMillis()

> Returns this Calendar's time value in milliseconds.

but doesn't explain why the discrepancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl represents time in seconds since epoch, while Java represents it in milliseconds (1/1000 of second) since epoch.  So Perl time is always 1000-times less then Java time.

Comment: Oh my gosh I completely missed that one. Thanks for clarifying.